# Terraria and Hamachi

Tags: terraria, hamachi

I have a Terraria server running at home for my friends to play. It works fine for them and myself when I play at home - but at work or on my mum's PC which are in different locations it doesn't.

When I try to join from either of these locations, the server is found, loaded and the name of the server is picked up etc. When I join I can see that the world has all the correct tiles (ie the houses around the spawning point are present, etc) but after about 1-2 seconds the connection is lost.

I'm on Hamachi at work at the moment and see that next to the computer that's running the Terraria server it says "relayed tunnel":

[image]

Does anyone know of this issue and a way to fix it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you decided to use Hamachi instead of using a pure server?

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by pure server to be honest.

Comment: Well, just without Hamachi. Could you not host a game directly without VPN software (just forward and open port 7777 on your router and firewall respectively)?

Comment: I have no idea (I'm a gamer not an IT ninja). Probably makes sense though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a problem with Terraria, its Hamachi not being able to get a direct connection to the other player and going via a relay.

Sometimes just restarting both Hamachi clients will fix the problem, but if that does not work you should forward the port Hamachi is listening on to one of you (Hamachi will try connecting from A to B *and* from B to A and only use a relay if neither is possible).